# Why can’t Pythagorean triples of this form exist, $\{a, b, c\}$, $\{2a, d, c\}$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, pythagorean-triples

Why can’t there exist two Pythagorean triples with the same hypotenuse, but one has a leg that is twice as long as a leg of the other?  Or why is there no integer solution to

$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$

$4a^2 + d^2 = c^2$

$a$ must be the even leg.

The existence would imply that
$c - 2a$, $c - a$, $c + a$, $c + 2a$ are all squares.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141778/discussion-on-question-by-keith-raskin-why-cant-pythagorean-triples-of-this-for).

Answer (score 3):

So I think I have found a proof that no such triples exist:

Suppose such a solution exists, thus as noted in the question $c-2a,\ c-a,\ c+a,\ c+2a$ are all squares. Rescaling, we will have rational squares $r^2,\ s^2, 1, t^2$ where $r^2 = 1-3a$, $s^2 = 1-2a$ and $t^2 = 1+a$. Thus $(6t^2,6rst)$ is a rational point on the elliptic curve $y^2 = x^3-17x^2+72x$  which has rank $0$ (I checked [LMFDB](http://www.lmfdb.org/EllipticCurve/Q/48/a/3) for this). We can now check each of the torsion points to see that none of them leads to a set of $r,s,t$ with an $a\neq 0$. (The torsion subgroup is generated by $(8,0)$ and $(6,6)$ according to LMFDB.) Of course there are ways to prove that the rank is $0$ and the torsion subgroup is as claimed without relying on computers but I decided to keep this short.

Comment: So, if a remains an integer, r and s are complex numbers.

Comment: No, $a$ does not remain an integer, but it is a rational number after the rescaling. So $r$ and $s$ are rational numbers also.

Comment: So, how did you get  'Thus $(6rst,6t^2)$ is a rational point on the elliptic curve ... "? The critical details are missing here.

Comment: I took the liberty of adding an LMFDB-link. Even though the database automagically switches to the minimal Weierstrass form, I think it is useful to have it for ease of reference (the required transformation is either easy to figure out or a useful refresher exercise). Anyway, if you object, I apologize, and roll it back.

Comment: The use of $a$ in $t^2=1+a$ is misleading. You meant something like $t^2=1+A$ where $A=a/(c+a)$. Also, it should be $r^2 = 1-3A$ and $s^2=1-2A$.