# Is it true that no two PPTs of the form {a, b, c}, {ka, d, c} exist for any whole number k > 1?

Tags: number-theory

How could we prove no two primitive Pythagorean triples of the form {a, b, c} and {ka, d, c} can exist for any whole number k > 1?

The existence implies that

c - ka, c - a, c + a, c + ka

are all squares of whole numbers.

The case of k = 2 has been proved here by scaling the list of squares and using an elliptic that should have a rational point based on products of the scaled squares, but can’t, disproving their existence. Multiple sketches of proof, curves, were given.

Comment: "has been proved here": can you link to "here"?

Comment: You were told that it is enough to consider only two equations. The rest is symmetrical and just has a different entry. $c=p^2+s^2 ; a=p^2-s^2$ $$c-a=2s^2 ; c+a=2p^2$$

Comment: This is almost certainly untrue, as the corresponding elliptic curves have positive rank (i.e. infinitely many rational points) quite frequently (conjecturally, half the time). For example, this is true for $k=7, 10, 11$ and $12$. There's a little work to do to map these points back to your original problem, but I'll leave that as an exercise.

Comment: See the proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4608479/why-can-t-pythagorean-triples-of-this-form-exist-a-b-c-2a-d-c=) for $k=2$.

Comment: One can find examples quickly also from pythagorean triples parametrization for $a,b,c$, and checking if $c^2-(ka)^2$ is a square. This finds for example $24^2+143^2=145^2=(6\cdot 24)^2+17^2$.

Comment: Ah, so no such triples for k = 2, 7, 10, 11, 12 . . . But we do have triples like {24, 143, 145}, {6•24, 17, 145} for k=6

Comment: Sketch of proof given ‘here’ 
c - 2a, c - a, c + a, c + 2a


A = a / (c + a)

t^2 = 1 + A = (c + 2a)/(c + a)
r^2 = 1 - 3A = (c - 2a)/(c + a)
s^2 = 1 - 2A = (c - a)/(c + a)

(6t^2, 6rst) would be a rational point on

y^2 = x^3 - 17x^2 + 72x    

(6rst)^2 = x(x - 8)(x - 9)
= 6t^2(6t^2 - 8)(6t^2 - 9)
= 6t^2(6A - 2)(6A - 3)
= 36t^2(1 - 3A)(1 - 2A)
= 36t^2r^2s^2

Then, checking https://lnkd.in/eKhD5g-8

the rank of that curve is 0 and the torsion subgroup is generated by (8,0) and (6,6). Checking torsion points, there can be no solution for r, s and t with nonzero a.

Comment: Amazing assistance!  Amazing free results!

Comment: Each of those triples {24, 143, 145} and {6•24, 17, 145} are the first in one of two infinite sequences of triples with the corresponding leg difference, 119 and 127. The sequence for 127 is generated by 8, 8 + 1, 2(8  + 1) + 8, … = 8, 9, 26, 61 … (and the other for 127 starts with 8 - 1 and 3•8 - 2•1, so 7, 22, 51, 124, … ). For 119, we start with 10 - 9, 3•10  - 2•9, … ==> 1, 12, 25, 62 … (the other sequence for 119 is 10, 10 +   9, … ==> 10, 19, 48, 115 …) each pair in each sequence generates PPTs by Euclid’s formula. Other ways to get a leg difference beget more pairs of sequences.

Comment: So those pairs of sequences above are specific to the forming of the leg differences by 2•8^2 - 1^2 and 2•10^2 - 9^2.  And the fact that each is a first pair of terms is likely just because they are relatively small PPTs.

Comment: For example, since 119 = 2•10^2 - 9^2 AND 2•8^2 - 3^2, there are two pairs of infinite sequences with that leg difference                            
10, 10 + 9, … ;                        10 - 9, 3•10 - 2•9, ….   

8, 8 + 3, … ;                             8 - 3, 3•8 - 2•3,…